# Declaring a project (module) as a dependecy in another project(another module) but failed

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I have created a gradle project named `my-root-project`, under which there are two other gradle projects: `shared` and `my-service`.

In my IntelliJ IDE, I have added `shared` and `my-service` as modules of `my-root-project`. The project structure overall looks like this:

```
-my-root-project

  -shared
    -build.gradle
    -settings.gradle

  -my-service
    -build.gradle
    -settings.gradle

-build.gradle
-settings.gradle
...
```

In the `settings.gradle` of `my-root-project` I have:

```
rootProject.name = 'my-root-project'
include ':shared'
include ':my-service'
```

In `build.gradle` of `my-service`, I would like to add `shared` as its project dependency:

```
...
dependencies {
   implementation project(':shared')
}
```

But I get error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my-service'.
> Project with path ':shared' could not be found in root project 'my-service'.
```

Then, I tried including `shared` also in the `settings.gradle` of `my-service`. (Above, I have already included it in `settings.gradle` of `my-root-project`).

Then, build again but get a new error:

```
Could not resolve project :shared.
Required by:
    project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Where am I wrong? I would like to have `shared` project be a dependency in `my-service`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you’re running your Gradle command from within the `my-service` project directory. As that project contains a `settings.gradle` file, Gradle considers the project to be the root project. Under this “root project”, there is no subproject called `shared`, so Gradle complains with the error you saw:

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my-service'.
> > Project with path ':shared' could not be found in root project 'my-service'.

I’d recommend to change two things (but either of them should get you rid of the error):

1. There should be only a single `settings.gradle` file in a multi-project build – in the root project, i.e., your `my-root-project`. If you look at [the Gradle docs for multi-project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/userguide/multi_project_builds.html), then you’ll see that there is only a single `settings.gradle` file in each sample project hierarchy.
2. I would run all Gradle commands from the root project directory. If you need to run a task in a subproject, then use the full path of the task, for example: `./gradlew :my-service:check`
   You can find more on executing tasks in multi-project builds in [the Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html).

Comment: Thanks! Exactly like what you explained.